# "Illegal offset type in isset or empty" when using a Twig macro

Tags: twig, grav

Using Grav v1.3.8 (running on PHP 5.6.30), I'm currently getting a Server error (*"Illegal offset type in isset or empty"*) when trying to render a Twig template that is using a macro.

What's interesting is that this only happens when I use the macro by itself. As soon as I append a filter, like `trim`, everything works as expected.

**The (shortened) macro file, `helpers.twig`:**

```
{% macro ascii(str) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {{ str|replace({
        'Á': 'A',
        'À': 'A',
        'Â': 'A',
        'Ã': 'A',
        ....
        'ƒ': 'f'
      })
    }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro ascii %}
```

**The template (MCVE):**

```
{% import 'macros/helpers.twig' as helpers %}

{% set img = helpers.ascii('günter-berger.jpg') %}
{% if page.media[img] is defined %}
    <img src="{{ page.media[img].url }}">
{% endif %}
```

This will produce the error. I narrowed it down to the `if` line. Apparently, the macro is working fine, but the condition will throw an error if fed the output of it, unfiltered. Adding any filter, like `trim` or `lower`, will get it to work again.

In other words, these work:

- `{% if page.media['günter-berger.jpg'] is defined %}`
- `{% if page.media[helpers.ascii('günter-berger.jpg')|trim] is defined %}`

But this will throw an error:

- `{% if page.media[helpers.ascii('günter-berger.jpg')] is defined %}`

However, trying [the same thing on twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/vmcsnw), all three seem to work there.
Maybe an issue with Grav? Can someone point out any possible causes?

Comment: It seems the macro is [not](https://twigfiddle.com/ua5gjw) the problem here though

Comment: @DarkBee you're right. Thanks to your hint, I was able to further narrow down the issue. Question has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot this, but a macro does not return a string but instead returns an instance of a `Twig_Markup`

```
{% set test = macro.ascii('Ghünter.jpg') %}
{{ dump(test) }}
```

Output : `object(Twig_Markup)#10679 (2) { ["content":protected]=> string(11) "Ghunter.jpg" ["charset":protected]=> string(5) "UTF-8" }`

Because the return type is an object you get this notification as you can't use objects as `index`. By using a filter on this instance, the `magic method` `__toString` method will be called, causing it to return a string, thus making it useable as `index` for an array

The only was to bypass this, would be writing a `filter` instead of a `macro`

Comment: Ha, I suspected something like this! Just a minute ago, I tried casting the result of the macro to string by using the `string` filter and that worked, too. However, this feels a bit brittle - removing the filter in the future will again lead to this error. Is there a better (more stable or elegant) way of going about this? Maybe a way to force a macro to actually return a string?

Comment: You can't force a macro to return a string. But you should be able to do sthing like this in grav:  `<?php add_filter('ascii', function($val) { return str_replace(['ü', 'Ü,] , ['u', 'u',], $val); });` and then access in it twig like `'günter-berger.jpg' | ascii`

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what caused the issue and how to work around the problem.

Comment: An alternate way of getting the macro to return a string is to use the spaceless filter. So for example this: `macro.ascii('Ghünter.jpg')|spaceless` should return a string.